# Server/Client software to push file changes

Tags: recommendation-engine

I was wondering if anyone can recommend a software(preferably free) that has a server/client setup where I can push a file change from the server to the clients on the network PC's? Its just one particular file that changes daily and I would like to just push it out to the clients instead of keeping users permissions as administrator to copy it down from a shared drive as its currently setup to do via application startup script.

Comment: Could you specify if your users require access to the server via smb? or would they require access out on the internet?

Comment: smb. The server does not have internet access.

Answer (score 1):

Add those users to a group, give that group read access to the file, they won't need admin privileges anymore.

As soon as you make a change to the file, they will pick up the changes.